# Misleading behaviour on Menu & Theme location

Tags: menus, navigation, init

I've got the following usual menu registration function:

```
function my_register_menus(){
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'text_Domain' ),
        'footer-menu'  => __( 'Footer Menu', 'text_Domain' ),
    ) );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_register_menus', 0 );
```

and this is what I call in my `header.php`:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ));
```

Now, in the

```
WP Admin > Nav Menus
```

when I assign a menu to the `primary-menu` location, the menu doesn't show at all in the theme.

If I un-check the menu location, the menu appears.

Comment: Try doing a single menu `function single_menu_reg() { register_nav_menu( 'primary-menu', __( 'Primary Menu', 'text_domain' ) ); } add_action( 'init', 'single_menu_reg', 0);` - this is just a test to see if something else is happening. As your code looks fine.

Comment: Hello @disinfor 
I've also tried the single `register_nav_menu` menu function but nope, same behaviour: when I assign the menu to that location the menu disapper, if I uncheck the location for the menu, it appears again. That's weird, I can't figure out what I'm missing. I also use Polylang, so I thought that had something to do with it, but I don't know...

Comment: Then you need to start troubleshooting. Deactivate all your plugins and activate them one by one until your menu breaks. Without seeing more code, I don't think we can necessarily help - since what you posted *should* work.